# docker registry with nginx: no such host

Tags: nginx, docker, registry

Here I setup two ubuntu machine which had run as docker registry. I just use the Docker Registry latest Image. Then I setup a ubuntu machine running Nginx which will proxy the request to either of the registries.

I changed the Nginx configuration file so I can see "/Docker registry server/" when I "curl" the Nginx server.

But things has been strange when I want to push my Image.

"dial tcp: docker-registry: no such host

Answer (score 0):

Because I setup 3 docker containers on 3 different hosts. Layers of one images maybe post to different registries.